Integrate result differs from what's expected
Trying to get a result for this Indefinite integral:
Integrate[1/(2*(x^4 + x^2 + 1)), x]

Mathematica v14 provides this result:
(I (Sqrt[1 - I Sqrt[3]] ArcTan[1/2 (-I + Sqrt[3]) x] - 
   Sqrt[1 + I Sqrt[3]] ArcTan[1/2 (I + Sqrt[3]) x]))/(2 Sqrt[6])

However if you actually manually work this out by applying partial fraction decomposition and completing the squares along with a few substitutions, the Indefinite Integral simplifies to:
(log(x^2+x+1) - log(x^2-x+1)) / 8+(atan((2x+1) / √3) + atan((2x-1) / √3)) / (4√3)

So which is correct? Or are they the same? Why is Mathematica having the imaginary number I in the output?   Why do they appear to be vastly different?
I assume we can ask Mathematical also to see if the 2 expressions are identical? But then it doesn't make sense why 1 would have I in the oputput and other does not.
Thanks
P.S. to make matters even more confusing, if I add FullSimplify to the result, I even get another starnge result:
FullSimplify[Integrate[1/(2*(x^4 + x^2 + 1)), x]]

Results to:
-(((-1)^(1/6) ((-1)^(1/6) ArcTan[(-1)^(5/6) x] + ArcTanh[(-1)^(2/3) x]))/(2 Sqrt[3]))

6th root of -1 doesn't even exist! Which I assume is where that I comes from above....

The sixth root of -1 does exist, it is complex. Look at (-1)^(1/6) // N and  ComplexListPlot[Callout[(-1)^(#/6)] & /@ Range[0, 6], Epilog -> {Dashed, Circle[]}]

Nice charts! amazing.....Thx!

First, Integrate[f[x], x] calculates an antiderivative, which may differ locally from any other antiderivative by a constant. By locally, I mean the difference between them is constant on any open set in the complex plane over which both antiderivatives are continuous.
Second, the theory of symbolic integration on which Integrate[] rests is built from complex analysis, and its results often differ from the typical real calculus built from high-school algebra. It is also refined for computer algorithms, which have different capacities than the human algorithms taught it the typical calculus course.
Third, getting from the Integrate[] result to the typical calculus result is tricky especially when trigonometry is involved. Sometimes it is better to accept what you get than to fight it. But below I can show you what the battle looks like in this case, which is simpler than normal, I guess, because normally I don't succeed:
res1 = Integrate[1/(2*(x^4 + x^2 + 1)), x];
res2 = ComplexExpand[
   res1,
   TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}
   ];
res3 = res2 /.
    {ArcTan[x_, y_] :> ArcTan[y/x], ArcTanh -> TrigToExp@*ArcTanh} // 
   Simplify;
res4 = res3 /.
   {ArcTan[z_] :> With[{s = Sign@Coefficient[Denominator[z], x]},
      ArcTan[
       FullSimplify[
        First@Ratios@
           TrigExpand@Through[{Cos, Sin}[s * Pi/6 + ArcTan[z]]]
        ]
       ]]};
res5 = res4 //
  Collect[# /. at_ArcTan :> at*$temp, $temp, Factor] /. $temp -> 1 &


(*  (ArcTan[(-1 + 2 x)/Sqrt[3]] + ArcTan[(1 + 2 x)/Sqrt[3]])/
     (4 Sqrt[3]) + 1/8 (-Log[1 - x + x^2] + Log[1 + x + x^2])  *)


Converting ArcTanh to  Log was fairly straightforward (TrigToExp). Rotating the branch cuts from the ArcTan terms was trickiest (res3 -> res4).  The branch cuts are given by the following:
FunctionDiscontinuities[res1, x, Complexes] // Reduce
FunctionDiscontinuities[res5, x, Complexes] // Reduce


(*
(Re[x] <= -(1/2) && (Im[x] == Sqrt[3] Re[x] || Im[x] == -Sqrt[3] Re[x])) ||
 (Re[x] >= 1/2 && (Im[x] == -Sqrt[3] Re[x] || Im[x] == Sqrt[3] Re[x]))

(Re[x] == -(1/2) && (Im[x] <= -(Sqrt[3]/2) || Im[x] >= Sqrt[3]/2)) ||
 (Re[x] == 1/2 && (Im[x] <= -(Sqrt[3]/2) || Im[x] >= Sqrt[3]/2))
*)


They need to be rotated from $\pm60^\circ$ to $\pm90^\circ$. The direction turned out nicely to match a coefficient of x.

Yes thanks very much Micheal. Nasser proved the 2 are equivalent, but your is what I was initially looking for: How do I arrive at one from the other. With a little Seasoning of philosophy mixed in!


So which is correct?

They both correct. To find if anti-derivative is correct or not, differentiate it and see if you get back the integrand. In this case both Mathematica result and yours do.
integrand = 1/(2*(x^4 + x^2 + 1));
anti1 = Integrate[integrand, x];
FullSimplify[D[anti1, x] - integrand]
(* 0 *)

And
anti2 = (Log[x^2 + x + 1] - Log[x^2 - x + 1])/8 + (ArcTan[(2 x + 1)/Sqrt[3]] + ArcTan[(2 x - 1)/Sqrt[3]])/(4*Sqrt[3])
FullSimplify[D[anti2, x] - integrand]
(* 0 *)

It is very common to obtain different looking anti-derivates for same integrand. Some tests grade such result, from A,B,C or F, as some are considered better quality than others, even though they are all mathematically correct.

Sure thanks @Nasser.  So I assume if we graph both the results also , should look same. But can be chart a function with Imaginary I as  part of it?   Nice test with the Derivative...

@Steve237 Try ReImPlot[{result1, result2}, {x, -1, 1}] or something like it. A better way would be ReImPlot[result1 - result2, {x, -1, 1}], which should show a piecewise-constant graph.

Nice!  @MichaelE2 So the differentials are in the order of 10^-17 !!! I assume this stems from the loss of conversion between Trig and Imaginary domain?  Which is most dead-accurate version? ....

@Steve237 The small differences are due to floating-point round-off errors. A one-bit error in the last place of a number $x$ has a magnitude of about $10^{-16}x$. For $1 \le x < 2$, it's $MachineEpsilon, which is 2.^-52 or 2.22045*10^-16. As for which is most accurate, my guess is that sometimes one result is closer to the exact value and sometimes the other. Each operation contributes a round-off error. Some errors cancel out; some make the error greater. Errors around 10^-17 seem rather too small to worry about.
